# Amazon ECS Task, how to get public IP in NodeJS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I have a task (written in NodeJS) running in an ECS Fargate cluster. The task has a public IP assigned to it, but I would like to know the public IP, inside the task.

Previously I ran on EC2 and there this was pretty straightforward. I just did:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const meta = new AWS.MetadataService()

async function getPublicIp() {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    meta.request("/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4", function (err, data) {
      if(err) {
        return reject(err)
      }

      resolve(data)
    })
  })
}
```

The problem is I find no such thing for ECS.

Comment: The most basic way would be to query `ifconfig.me` or similar service. Using curl it would be `curl ifconfig.me`. You could also use aws sdk to query for task descriptions to get the ip. There is also [task metadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-metadata-endpoint.html), but I'm not sure it will have info about public ip.

Comment: "You could also use aws sdk to query for task descriptions to get the ip". That's the theory, but I have no idea on how to do this.